# Как сделать глобальный хук на C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Очень неплохо описана тема [здесь](http://devivan.blogspot.com/2012/03/c.html), и готовый класс даже есть, но увы, этот хук срабатывает только тогда, когда форма является активной, как же сделать хук даже если форма  свернута и не является в данный момент вообще как-либо задействована? Я бы даже это назвал супер-глобальный хук.

Я вот создал такой хук:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace com
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13; // Номер глобального LowLevel-хука на клавиатуру
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100; // Сообщения нажатия клавиши

    private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = hookProc;

    private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public void SetHook()
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _proc, hInstance, 0);
    }

    public static void UnHook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
    }

    public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            //////ОБРАБОТКА НАЖАТИЯ
            myfunc(); // ошибка
            return (IntPtr)1;
        }
        else
            return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam);
    }

    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // убираем хук
        UnHook();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetHook();
    }

    public void myfunc(){

        MessageBox.Show("Hello!");

    }

}
}
```

Но проблема в том что я не могу запустисть свою функцию в таком случае, возникает ошибка:

> Ошибка    1   Для нестатического поля,
> метода или свойства
> "com.Form1.myfunc()" требуется ссылка
> на объект

Comment: просьба ссылки не тыкать, а код(класс) здесь выкладывать, мне так легче разбираться будет, да и другим может понадобиться.

Comment: эта тема легко гуглится, не вижу смысла копипастить код ещё и сюда

Comment: как-то все запутано, готовый класс бы.

Comment: Тут все тыкают ссылки на темы с хуками. А человек задал вопрос именно по c#. Решение: Попробуйте myfunk() сделать static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Как установить Windows ловушка в Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804)

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

[Global System Hooks in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET)

Comment: пока без англ. попробовал 1-ую ссылку, там хук на мышь, а на клавиатуру есть на русском?

Comment: Вот на русском 
http://wincode.org/dotnet/global-keyboard-hook-in-dotnet
Есть много готовых библиотек для установки хуков в C#, вот одна из них http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Answer (score -2):

Все работает , определи экземпляр класса

```
Form1 B = new Form1(); 
B.myfunc();
```

и все заработает