# C# как в фоновом режиме отследить нажатие определенной кнопки

Tags: c#

В общем задача такова: нужна программа, которую пользователь сам запустит, она должна отслеживать нажатие кнопки F8 всегда, т.е программа может быть свернута и т.д., но она запущена.
Был бы рад готовому коду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130391/winforms-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c) уже поднимался на форуме, посмотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130391#130397)