# Открыть форму с кнопки на клавиатуре c#

Tags: c#, winforms

У коллеги "Инженерный калькулятор" открывается при нажатии на F7, при этом программа закрыта (наверное, весит в памяти где-то).
Как реализуется такой "бинд" в формах c#?

Comment: Вам нужны использовать глобальные хуки. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130391/Как-сделать-глобальный-хук-на-c/130397#130397

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Требуется использовать системные функции как я понял [тут](http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-register-a-global-hotkey-for-your-application-in-c/) описано решение проблемы(ресурс на английском, код привожу ниже). По нажатию горячих клавиш в примере выводится MessageBox, Вам нужно запустить вашу программу - `Process.Start(@"c:\myCalc.exe")`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GlobalHotkeyExampleForm
{
    public partial class ExampleForm : Form
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        enum KeyModifier
        {
            None = 0,
            Alt = 1,
            Control = 2,
            Shift = 4,
            WinKey = 8
        }

        public ExampleForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int id = 0;     // The id of the hotkey. 
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, (int)KeyModifier.Shift, Keys.A.GetHashCode());       // Register Shift + A as global hotkey. 
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
            {
                /* Note that the three lines below are not needed if you only want to register one hotkey.
                 * The below lines are useful in case you want to register multiple keys, which you can use a switch with the id as argument, or if you want to know which key/modifier was pressed for some particular reason. */

                Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);                  // The key of the hotkey that was pressed.
                KeyModifier modifier = (KeyModifier)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);       // The modifier of the hotkey that was pressed.
                int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();                                        // The id of the hotkey that was pressed.


                MessageBox.Show("Hotkey has been pressed!");
                // do something
            }
        }

        private void ExampleForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0);       // Unregister hotkey with id 0 before closing the form. You might want to call this more than once with different id values if you are planning to register more than one hotkey.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, можно обойтись элементарным назначением клавиш быстрого вызова в свойствах ярлыка для нужного приложения:

Клик правой клавишей мышки на ярлыке: Свойства > Ярлык > Быстрый вызов (в английской Windows: Properties > Shortcut > Shortcut key).

Алфавитно-цифровые клавиши будут работать в комбинации с <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, а функциональные клавиши, типа <kbd>F7</kbd> можно задать и без модификаторов.