# Обработка нажатия клавиш winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Процесс делает некоторые действия в браузере и на рабочем столе. Соответственно фокус находится вне winforms приложения во время исполнения. Вопрос, как задать обработку клавиш, которая оказывала воздействия именно на приложение. Нашел несколько решений, но все они рассматривались при условии, что приложение находилось в фокусе.

Comment: Кейлоггер пишете?

Comment: @Raider Приложение уже написано) это бот под одну соцсеть. Обработка нажатия, это скорее для удобства использования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваше окно теряет фокус, но вы все равно хотите, что бы оно реагировало на нажатия клавиш клавиатуры, то решением тут будет глобальный хук на клавиатуру (можно и на мышь, кстати, тоже).

В целом, при запуске приложения вы регистрируете свой обработчик нажатий на клавиатуру, обрабатываете нажатия, потом передаете события дальше (могут быть помимо вашего и другие хуки в системе), а при завершении работы приложения корректно снимаете свой хук.

Тема работы с клавиатурными хуками поднималась тут, например, вот [ответ на аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/130397/222168), в котором есть ссылки на статьи и реализации хуков.

Или вот, [пример ответа с кодом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581155/222168) (не буду его копипастить сюда).

Есть еще вот [такая статья](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) с примером на английском.

И есть еще [замечательная статья](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmandreev/2010/11/29/windows-c/) на русском в блоге Miccrosoft, с примером.
Статья со временем может переехать или исчезнуть, потому код оттуда позволю себе продублировать тут. В примере есть и назначение хука, и его снятие, и обработка сочетания клавиш, в частности, обрабатывается <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Как говорит автор,

> Пример этот будет работать как на 32х так и на 64 битной Windows. Программа выводит в отладочную консоль нажатия на клавиши в любом приложении, а также производит блокировку нажатия Alt+Tab. Как вы уже понимаете, перехват клавиатуры ведется на уровне всех приложений.

Итак:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HookDemoApp
{
   internal class HookDemoHelper
   {
       private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;


       private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback;
       private IntPtr m_hHook;

       [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
       private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(
        int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate lpfn,
        IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);


       [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
       private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);


       [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
       private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(IntPtr lpModuleName);


       [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
       private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(
        IntPtr hhk,
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


       private IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       {
           if (nCode < 0)
           {
               return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
           }
           else
           {
               var khs = (KeyboardHookStruct)
                         Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam,
                         typeof (KeyboardHookStruct));
           
               Debug.Print("Hook: Code: {0}, WParam: {1},{2},{3},{4} ",
                         nCode, wParam, lParam,
                         khs.VirtualKeyCode,
                         khs.ScanCode, khs.Flags, khs.Time);
           
               Debug.Print(khs.VirtualKeyCode.ToString());


               if (khs.VirtualKeyCode == 9 &&
                  wParam.ToInt32() == 260 &&
                  khs.ScanCode == 15) //alt+tab
               {
                   System.Console.WriteLine("Alt+Tab pressed!");
                   IntPtr val=new IntPtr(1);
                   return val;                    
               }
               else
               {
                   return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
               }           
           }
       }

       [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
       private struct KeyboardHookStruct
       {
           public readonly int VirtualKeyCode;
           public readonly int ScanCode;
           public readonly int Flags;
           public readonly int Time;
           public readonly IntPtr ExtraInfo;
       }

       private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


       public void SetHook()
       {
           m_callback =LowLevelKeyboardHookProc;
           m_hHook =SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
            m_callback,
            GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero),0);
       }

       public void Unhook()
       {
           UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook);
       }
}
```

}

Всё...